# Menu option not available under appearance tab in WP dashboard (integrate custom html template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am new to WordPress

I have integrated my HTML template to WordPress. However I am looking for a menu option within WordPress dashboard like other template but couldn't see the menu option.

Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menu

Could anyone suggest how I am going to see the menu option or where to add menu file so that I can see the menu option in WP dashboard.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You need to add menu support in your functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
```

Secondly, You can register a menu

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'textdomain' ),
    )
);
```